# Best way to read output of shell command

Tags: shell, vim, shellexecute

In Vim, What is the best (portable and fast) way to read output of a shell command? This output may be binary and thus contain nulls and (not) have trailing newline which matters. Current solutions I see:

1. Use `system()`. Problems: does not work with NULLs.
2. Use `:read !`. Problems: won’t save trailing newline, tries to be smart detecting output format (dos/unix/mac).
3. Use `!` with redirection to temporary file, then `readfile(, "b")` to read it. Problems: two calls for fs, `shellredir` option also redirects stderr by default and it should be less portable (`'shellredir'` is mentioned here because it is likely to be set to a valid value).
4. Use `system()` and filter outputs through `xxd`. Problems: very slow, least portable (no equivalent of `'shellredir'` for pipes).

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a **text** editor. If you care about NULs, trailing EOLs and (possibly) conflicting encodings, you need to use a hex editor anyway?

If I need this amount of control of my operations, I use the xxd route indeed, with

```
:se binary
```

One nice option you seem to miss is insert mode *expression register* insertion:

> <kbd>C-r</kbd>`=system('ls -l')`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This may or may not be smarter/less intrusive about character encoding business, but you could try it if it is important enough for you.

Or you could use Perl or Python support to effectively use `popen`

Rough idea:

```
:perl open(F, "ls /tmp/ |"); my @lines = (<F>); $curbuf->Append(0, @lines)
```

Comment: You can try `<C-r>=system('printf ''\x00''')<CR>`. It won’t output anything, while `:%!printf '\x00'` will put single NULL viewed as `^@` in the buffer (big problem: `:%!printf '\x00\r\n'` does the same).

Comment: Problem here is that I do not want to have two functions: “read command into buffer”, normally achievable by “%!” and “put command output into file” and I can’t say I won’t ever need more. Analog to `readfile()` is the most flexible solution in this case.

Comment: Just thought of using perl/python support; see answer for starter